# How to reset BigDecimal to zero

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Hallo,
I have a BigDecimal temp variable, I want it to be reusable in a function. Is there a way for me to reset this variable to zero if the value is greater than zero?

THanks @!

Comment: You would learn the answer to this pretty quickly by reading [the documentation for BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) (the *first word* of which is "immutable").  One of the best things about Java is its enormous and [thoroughly-documented](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) standard libraries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

BigDecimal is immutable, and instances cannot be modified. However, you could do something like:

```
public void myMethod(BigDecimal b) {
    BigDecimal zero = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    if (b.compareTo(zero) > 0)
        b = zero;
    // Do stuff with b here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't change the value. `BigDecimals` are Immutable.  You need to create a new one.

Comment: Better to use `BigDecimal.ZERO` instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @Stephen, true, but I was saying "create a new one" as opposed to reusing one in a function.